# Operand types are incompatible "int*" and "int"

Tags: c++, int

I've been getting this error, I don't understand the problem in my code

//prior to this there is a menu selection where you choose a version

```
if (&config_system.item.Antiaimtypedsy == 2 || &config_system.item.Antiaimtypedsy == 3)
```

and here is the declared variable

```
int Antiaimtypedsy;
```

LMK what I need to change I am so confused and have been stuck on this.

edit: The error is in the ==

Comment: What do you think the `&` before `config_system.item.Antiaimtypedsy` does? The reason I ask is because I'm assuming you didn't just throw it in for no reason: you thought it does something. I'm trying to figure out what the something is so we can prevent that misconception from happening in the future.

Comment: I was trying to reference the value for antiaimtypedsy

Comment: When `&` is used in a type, it's a reference, like `int& a = b;`. When it's used on an already-existing variable, like `int* a = &b;`, it's an operator that returns the address of that variable (unless it's been overloaded, which isn't common). So it has two uses. That are similar, but not THAT similar. I found it pretty confusing when I was learning C++ from C originally.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to take the address of the value, you just need the value. Additionally, if you need to compare it against multiple possibilities, use `switch`:

```
switch (config_system.item.Antiaimtypedsy) {
  case 2:
  case 3:
    // ...
    break;
}
```

The error is not `==`, it's the incorrect types caused by `&`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `&` which is the address of operator. That will give a pointer to the value, which will be an `int*`. As you found out, you can't properly compare an `int` and an `int*`.

Just use the `int` itself instead:

```
if (config_system.item.Antiaimtypedsy == 2 || config_system.item.Antiaimtypedsy == 3)
```